# Caching issue with Rails 4 and Nginx + Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, nginx

Occasionally my Rails Application might crash because of any bug and when accessing specific URLs at production, someone might land at the /500.html page.

So far everything is normal. We can see through the logs what the problem was and then fix. However, in order to view the page correctly we have to clear the browser cache, otherwise we are redirected again to /500.html

Is there anyway to prevent that?

I describe an example workflow below:

1. Navigate to www.whatever.com/order/view/4444
2. Because of a problem in our data/code the user is redirected to www.whatever.com/500.html
3. We view the logs, identify the problem and fix it
4. If I DO NOT clear the browser cache, after trying to navigate to www.whatever.com/order/view/4444 I am redirected to /500.html again
5. If I clear the cache, everything is working normally

Is there anything we can do in Rails or Nginx configuration so that I won't have to clear the browser cache after changing the Rails app?

**nginx.conf**

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

**myapp.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/xxx/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_friendly_error_pages on;
}
```

Comment: Is there something in javascript that is navigating the user to another page that then doesn't exist? Or maybe there is something that logs in a user automatically and then redirecting?

Comment: No, user is logged in normally. I have seen that on the request the user is redirected (the redirect is cached probably?) without any request to the application server.

Comment: Can you post your nginx config?

Comment: Do you have a custom redirect to 500 page or it is just standard one?

Comment: User gets redirected to 500 page if there is an error in the application, so actually if I was running the app in development mode, I wouldn't be redirected but the classic Rails error page would be displayed

Comment: Can you confirm that you have passenger_friendly_error_pages on in production? That seems like an odd choice since it would provide your users with code specific details about the error.

Comment: By default, nginx redirects with response code 302. Try changing response code to 307. Something like this; `error_page 500 502 503 504 =307 /50x.html`

Comment: @mentalic have you tried my solution?

Comment: @beydogan No. I added proxy_cache_valid 301 1m; at the config and it seems to solve the issue but I am not sure that it is the correct answer.

Comment: @mentalic is it happening only in Chrome by any chance? If yes, it is how Chrome is trying to be smart...

Comment: @marek No, its happening to every browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. We had entered the following at config/routes.rb in order to display custom error messages. So actually 500 and 422 response codes were handled as redirects (and therefore cached).

```
get '/500', :to => redirect('/500.html')
get '/422', :to => redirect('/422.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

make sendfile off  on nginx config file like the following

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        off;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    index   index.html index.htm;
```